# Regex JSON schema field must have 1-9 digits, but 1-9 zeros with no other digits is rejected

Tags: regex, json

With a JSON schema pattern I seek to pass positive integers from one to 9 digits inclusive.

Leading zeros and trailing zeros are good.

All zeros from 1 to 9 digits (ie the number when converted would equal zero) are invalid.

Valid input examples:

```
123456789
012345678
123
0123
```

Invalid input examples:

```
0
000
0000000
An Empty string
1234d5
123456789123
```

I have tried variations on

```
^(?!0{1,9})[0-9]{1,9}$
```

but this falsely fails valid leading zero numbers.

Any ideas gladly accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this simply add the end of string `$` anchor to your Negative Lookahead.

```
^(?!0{1,9}$)[0-9]{1,9}$
          ^
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK7sA5/2) | [Explanation](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%28%3F%210%7B1%2C9%7D%24%29%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C9%7D%24&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: That works like a bought one in my unit tests thank you.  An alternative that one of the people at work just came up with is here: (^[0-9]{1,9}$)(?<!^0+$)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regexp, just say what you mean.

```
!isNaN(x) && +x !== 0 && x.length >=1 && x.length <= 9
```